# Collapsible Toolbar layout with listview

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I tried a lot to use CollapsibleToolbar with listview. Actually I have to implement Expandable listview inside Collapsible Toolbar. I already implemented recycleview in my other screen. If there is any way with recycle view I will change my code. But I have to complete this tedious task.

Comment: There are probably listeners conflict

Comment: @Oceinic : Then how can I do ExpandibleListView with CollapsibleToolbar.